# How To Store Data of add more textbox in database using AJAX or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have created one dynamic text box using Jquery/JavaScript. User can click on Add More Button JavaScript will add another input box in which user can enter some data.

Problem :- JavaScript is working fine but I'm unable to get my head around how to store those data in data base. i need help on php or Ajax to pass these user data to database. Below are Parameter which i want to pass

1. Hotel ID
2. Cancellation ID
3. (Dynamic Userdata)++1

Below Are mention my Codes.

JavaScript :-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; 
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);     
                var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
                <!--  newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'from' + newNum).attr('name', 'from' + newNum); -->
                $('#from1').attr('id', 'from' + newNum).attr('name', 'from' + newNum);
                $('#to1').attr('id', 'to' + newNum).attr('name', 'to' + newNum);
                $('#rate1').attr('id', 'rate' + newNum).attr('name', 'rate' + newNum);
                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');
            });
            $('#btnDel').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length; 
                $('#input' + num).remove();    
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');
                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#sub').click(function() {

            var from1=$("#from1").val();
            var to1=$("#to1").val();
            var rate1=$("#rate1").val();
            var from2=$("#from2").val();
            var to2=$("#to2").val();
            var rate2=$("#rate2").val();

             var num = $('.clonedInput').length; //number of times clicked

            $( "p" ).html( "<b>Single:</b> " + from1+ to1+rate1+ from2+ to2+rate2);
            $( "p" ).html("number"+num);

            })
            });
    </script>
```

HTML CODE :-

```
<form id="myForm">
    <tr id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
        <td> <input type="text" name="hotel_id" id="1" /></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="from1" id="from1" /></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="to1" id="to1" /></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="rate1" id="rate1" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <div>
    <tr><td></td><td></td>
       <td> <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />&nbsp;<input type="button" id="sub" value="submit" /></td>

    </tr>
    </div>
</form>
```

Please help me with this...

Comment: you can take all your input in array, means, you can give name=from[], etc.

Comment: from your `html` it doesn't seems you are creating only one `textfield` using `js`, instead you are creating a whole row which has four `input text`s (*hotel_id*, *from*, *to*, *rate*). Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i would do is,

Start with naming all your custom inputs the same, like "custom1" and then get your javascript to increase the last number by one each time, like "custom2", "custom3", and so on.

Then i would make a loop in my php script checking if empty() on "custom1", and just make that number increase for each time, if then one comes up empty, you have reached the end, meaning you can exit out of the loop. and then you have all your values you can insert where ever you want.

I will try showing you some example code below.

```
 for ($x=1; $x=0; $x++) {
  if (!empty($_POST["custom".$x]) {
    //The user have this custom field, and type something in it.
  } else {
    //This is the end of the custom fields.
    $x=0;
  }
 }
```

Comment: I think you are not getting my problem correctly. The problem I am facing here is that i have already captured javascript variables in var from1, to1 etc, and now i want to convert these into php variables so that i can save it into database . I am not able to achieve it.Please reconsider my problem. Any thanks will be really appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, then you can use this, when it goes into the if statement, you know that the post is not empty, and you can just assign a var to that, or even insert into database from there.